# Nemo Filemanager suddenly looks different

Tags: linux-mint, file-manager, nemo, gnome2

Today I started Nemo and noticed it's new (ugly) look which looks like some kind of fallback mode: [image]
When looking at the package history, I only see recent updates of phonon packages and the installation of wireshark and minitube. The current version is 2.0.8, downgrading to version 1.8.4-1 didn't help.

Answer (score 9):

It may be too late for you, but `nemo -q` did the trick for me.
I had the exact same problem.

Answer (score -1):

It is about your desktop theme.Put your themes in `/usr/share/themes`.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with themes or versions. For some unknown reason it happens out of the blue for a Nemo window which is already open in the old look and feel. The only fix is a complete power off and restart, until it happens again.